# Handle duplicates in Structured Streaming Databricks [PySpark]

Tags: pyspark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming

I am developing an application with Structured Streaming in Databricks in which I would like to control repeated events. So far the application does:

- Reads an XML formatted event
- Converts it to a DF
- Does a Group By with Windowing
- Finally it saves it in a Storage Account.

What I would like now is not to drop the duplicates with a `.dropDuplicates()` but to identify them and save them so that each incoming event is checked to see if it has been processed before or not. I am developing with PySpark.

I have tried saving the event ids in a table. But I don't want it to be a table as it would be consuming too much memory over time.

Is there any approach with which I can manage this?

Thanks!!

Comment: In which format the DF is saved in the storage account?

Comment: @LuizViola In JSON format